# Error on debugging in protractor typescript cucumber code in vscode - Cannot read source map file | ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, typescript, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

vs code version - 1.47.2

launch.js file

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
       "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "BDD-Debug",
        "protocol": "auto",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\node_modules\\protractor\\bin\\protractor",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "args": [
          "${workspaceFolder}\\transform\\config\\protractor.conf.js",
          "--cucumberOpts.tags",
          "@debug"
         ],
        "preLaunchTask": "npm: build",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/test/features/*.feature"],
        "smartStep": true
     }
    ]
   }
```

Error in console:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe    c:\Users\vn50ihd\WM_Project\GD_CCPA_QA_Automation\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor C:\Users\vn50ihd\WM_Project\GD_CCPA_QA_Automation\transform\config\protractor.conf.js -- 
    cucumberOpts.tags @debug
    Debugger listening on

file:///C:/Users/vn50ihd/WM_Project/GD_CCPA_QA_Automation/e2e/model/pageObjects/affirmation.page.ts: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\vn50ihd\WM_Project\GD_CCPA_QA_Automation\e2e\model\e2e\model\pageObjects\transform\data:application\json;charset=utf-8;base64,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
```

Comment: Can you try setting source map to false on your launch.js file. Does your website have a source map file?

Comment: this issue is because of vs code 1.47.2 .  i degraded the version and it worked fine